# iTextSharp PDF table too much columns Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf, itext

I am using `PdfPTable` to generate `PDF's` and following is my `relevant code` which loops through the `data from db`.

The problem here is if there are 10 or more columns the PDF design gets horrible. Is there any way in `iTextSharp` that Columns gets auto shifted in PDF by specifying Columns i require & rest columns are shifted on next page.

```
   // Table Head
   foreach (var q in tempColumnNames)
    {
        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(q, fntTableFont));               
        table.AddCell(cell);
    }

   // Table Body
    for (int i = 0; i < model.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < model[i].Count(); j++)
        {
                PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(model[i][j].ToString(), fntTableFont));
                table.AddCell(cell);
        }                                
    }
```

Comment: Can you just use a bigger page size?

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing automatic but you can use `PdfPtable.WriteSelectedRows` to write only the required sections.